# MPAndroidChart - Linechart/LineDataSet color problem with points (space between points)

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I set the color of my LineDataSet to white

```
lineDataSet.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

And it's white but there is a problem with the spaces between points. Look at this screenshot:

[image]

You can see that it's not a white line but there are "grey" spaces.

How can I change the color or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing circles at points. Try follow with your line data set for that line:

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm already calling setDrawCircles(false) but still have this issue.